# How to resolve async function inside another function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, async-await

Hello I have this function:

```
  const getImageSize = (url) => {
    const img = new Image()
    img.src = url
    return img.onload = async function() {
      
      return{
        height: this.height,
        width: this.width,
        scale: parseInt(this.height / this.width)
      }
    }
    
  }
```

and I call it like this

```
  const test = async () =>{
    const imageSize = await getImageSize(data[0].image.url)
    console.log(imageSize)
  }
```

I get the function itself but not the values.
How can I solve this?

This is the log:

```
ƒ () {
    var self = this,
        args = arguments;
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      var gen = fn.apply(self, args);

      function _next(value) {
        asyncGeneratorStep…
```

Comment: You need to use an explicit promise (`new Promise`) and not the `async` keyword to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

`async` is just syntax sugar of `Promise`. For this case you can just return a promise like:

```js
  const getImageSize = (url) => {
    const img = new Image()
    img.src = url
    let resolve
    img.onload = function() {
      resolve({
        height: this.height,
        width: this.width,
        scale: parseInt(this.height / this.width)
      })
    }

    return new Promise(r => resolve = r)
  }
```

Comment: thx this works.